# When should ImageIO stop reading from InputStream?

Tags: java, inputstream, javax.imageio

I am trying make a server that receives a JPG image over the newtork in Java.

```
isr = socket.getInputStream();
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(isr);
```

I would like to finish reading, but keep the socket connection. ImageIO stops only when I close the connection. It also stops when I send the same image twice.

Comment: please rephrase question. I don't understand the problem

Comment: I would like to keep the connection.

Answer (score -1):

ImageIO.read should continue reading from the input stream until it has the entire file, at which point it stops reading. It is then teh responsibility of the caller to call close on the input stream.

You don't send any data from the client to the server to tell it you are done reading. Just close the connection.

If the server sends the same image twice, or sends two different images, you must make two socket connections, or use some other method to read the data. To the best of my knowledge, there's no way for ImageIO.read to read two images.

Comment: Wrong. ImageIO creates the InputStream to read the image in. It manages caching, etc. and it closes the inputStream. The caller can't close the input stream.

Comment: @llappall I'm talking about ImageIO.read(InputStream), the function that the OP referenced in the question. It does not create the InputStream: it is passed in as a parameter. And to quote from the Java docs, "This method does not close the provided InputStream after the read operation has completed; it is the responsibility of the caller to close the stream, if desired." Perhaps you are thinking if ImageIO.read(URL). I suppose I should have clarified which of the overloaded versions of the function name I was referring to, but sometimes you have to read the question to understand the answer.

Comment: Oh, and it appears from the question that ImageIO.read(URL) wouldn't work in this case. He doesn't have a URL to start with -- he has a socket. Where he got the socket is not specified in the question.